# Will a Java 8 Stream.forEach( x -> {} ); do anything?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am controlling the Consumer that get's to this forEach so it may or may not be asked to perform an action.

```
list.parallelStream().forEach( x-> {} );
```

Streams being lazy Streams won't iterate, right? Nothing will happen is what i expect. Tell me if i am wrong, please.

Comment: Check the generated bytecode, but I'd expect to see an optimisation here.

Comment: ForEach is a terminal op, which trigger evaluation of the stream pipeline.  The elements will be generated and passed to the do-nothing lambda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will traverse the whole stream, submitting tasks to fork-join pool, splitting the list to parts and passing all the list elements to this empty lambda. Currently it's impossible to check in runtime whether the lambda expression is empty or not, thus it cannot be optimized out.

Similar problem appears in using `Collector`. All collectors have the `finisher` operation, but in many cases it's an identity function like `x -> x`. In this case sometimes the code which uses collectors can be greatly optimized, but you cannot robustly detect whether the supplied lambda is identity or not. To solve this an additional collector characteristic called [`IDENTITY_FINISH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html#IDENTITY_FINISH) was introduced instead. Were it possible to robustly detect whether supplied lambda is identity function, this characteristic would be unnecessary.

Also look at [JDK-8067971](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8067971) discussion. This proposes creating static constants like `Predicate.TRUE` (always true) or `Predicate.FALSE` (always false) to optimize operations like `Stream.filter`. For example, if `Predicate.TRUE` is supplied, then filtering step can be removed, and if `Predicate.FALSE` is supplied, then stream can be replaced with empty stream at this point. Again were it possible to detect in runtime that the supplied predicate is always true, then it would be unnecessary to create such constants.

Comment: Do you have any sources or evidence for this claim? The claim seems reasonable, but I'd personally expect to see an empty stream function optimized out (assuming it's indeed always an empty lambda, which the question doesn't actually make clear).

Comment: Great edit. I wonder if the JIT compiler will eventually support optimization around lambdas, as that seems like a nice optimization feature to eventually implement.

Comment: The compiler may be able to optimize some things for *sequential* streams once everything inlines into a single loop, but for parallel streams the cross-thread task queues are essentially intransparent to the JITs. The stream-pipeline would have to do some sort of introspection on the lambdas to perform such optimizations.